# How to return inner array of items from $http / JSON with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, servicestack-text

I'm trying to return the items from a JSON response and cannot figure out the syntax.  The response is a custom ServiceStack DTO (notice the inner array, called "Items"):

```
{"Items":[{"Id":"ABC1234","Name":"Tests-TestItem01","Desc":"Test Item 01"}]}
```

I have a AngularJS service with a method `getAll()`:

```
    function getAll() {
        return $http.get('http://servername.com/TestItems/GetAll')
            .then(getAllComplete)
            .catch(function(message) {
                exception.catcher('XHR Failed for Applications')(message);
                $location.url('/');
            });

        function getAllComplete(data, status, headers, config) {
            //return data.data[0].data.results;
            logger.info(data[0]);
            return data[0];
        }
    }
```

And I have a controller that is trying to use this service:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('testmodule')
        .controller('TestModule', TestModule);

    function TestModule(testItemSvc, logger) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.testItems = [];
        vm.title = "Test Items";
        vm.activate = activate;

        activate();

        function activate()
        {
            return getTestItems().then(function(){
               // Log and announce
                logger.info('Test Items loaded');
            });
        }

        function getTestItems(){
            return testItemSvc.getAll().then(function(data){
                vm.testItems = data;
                return vm.testItems;
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

I can see the response coming back (which is where I obtained the JSON) but I cannot determine how to return the items.  That's where all of the fumbling was in `getAllComplete()`.

**Edit:**
I added an `activate()` function and a toastr popup to show when the promise was successfully filled.  It *DOES* fire.  And, inside of my view HTML I am successfully binding to `vm.title`.  However, I am using `ng-repeat` to loop through `vm.testItems` and it never shows anything.

Comment: why aren't you inject your service to the controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http.get` returns a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) of an object with the *properties* that you have listed as function parameters. Try the following

```
function getAll() {
    function errorHandler (message) {
        exception.catcher('XHR Failed for Applications')(message);
        $location.url('/');
    }

    function successHandler(response) {
        return response.data.Items;
    }

    return $http.get('http://servername.com/TestItems/GetAll')
        .then(successHandler, errorHandler);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Alex!  Binding to response.data.Items was the piece that was stumping me.  The example I was looking at showed data being an array (data[0]).  It's working perfectly now.  :)